# PHP- Form Validation Errors

Tags: php, html, validation

This is my first time validating, I am having the hardest time have spent endless hours on this already. I have a registration form that needs to be validated, i have tried 2 scripts for this. The script that works best can be seen below: however every time I try to echo the error message to display under my text field i receive the following error messages:

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: c_email in **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhpProject2/Reg_1.php** on line **161**

Notice: Undefined variable: c_emailErr in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhpProject2/Reg_1.php on line 163

Notice: Undefined variable: c_pass1Err in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhpProject2/Reg_1.php on line 169

C_emailErr and c_pass1Err are both defined.

any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
         <section class="container">
        <form id="myform " class="Form" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" accept-charset="utf-8">

            <!--<div id="first">-->
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" value="<?= $c_email ?>" required >
            <br>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $c_emailErr; ?></span>
            <br>

            <figure>
                <input class ="login-field" type="password" id="pass1" name="pass1" value="<?= $c_pass1 ?>" placeholder="Password"  maxlength="30" required>
                <br>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $c_pass1Err; ?></span>
                <br>
                <input class ="login-field" type="password" id="pass2" name="pass2" value="" placeholder=" Confirm password" maxlength="30" required><!--<span class="error"><?php //echo $c_pass2Err;              ?></span>-->
                <div id="messages"></div>
            </figure>
            <p class="remember_me">
            </p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-default">
            <br>
        </form>

        <?php

        ?>

    </form>
</section>
```

PHP

```
 <?php
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


                    $c_email = $_POST['email'];
                    $c_pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
                    $c_pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
                    $c_emailErr = $c_pass1Err = $c_pass2Err = "";
                    //Checking the email address
                    if (!filter_var($c_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                        echo ("<b  id='email'> This is a valid email address </b>");
                    } else {
                        echo ("<b id='email'> Email is not a valid email address</b>");
                    }
                    if (strlen($c_pass1) <= '8') {
                        echo "<b>Your Password Must Contain At Least 8  Characters!</br>";
                        //check passwords
                    } elseif ($c_pass1 == $c_pass2) {
                        $q = "INSERT INTO Cus_Register(Cus_Email,Cus_Password,Cus_confirm_password) VALUES (?,?,?)";
                        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);
                        //new
                        // $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_c);
                        //debugging
                        //$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_c)  or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $c_email, $c_pass1, $c_pass2);


                        if ($q) {
                            echo "<script> alert('registration sucessful')</script>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<b>Oops! Your passwords do not </b>";
                    }
                }

                ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Is both the PHP and HTML code contained in the same file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining those variables, but you are defining them inside of an `if` block.. Move them outside of the `if` block.

```
<?php
 $c_emailErr = $c_pass1Err = $c_pass2Err = "";

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $c_email = $_POST['email'];
     $c_pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
     $c_pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
```

Comment: OMG! was that it. You are alive saver! thank you so much

Comment: No problem! The old second pair of eyes thing :)